# Redirect fails in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, window.location

Here is a piece of code in PHP written in a separate file called *core.php* and this is included in *register.php*

```
if(($retuserkey = $this->dbcontroller->dbregister($email, $contact)) > 0){  
    //if user was successfuly registered send an email where he can activate his account!
    $this->mailer->sendForReg($email,$hash,$flname);

    echo "<script>alert('An activation link is sent to your email id. Please check you spam folder too. Please follow the link to complete the registration.'); window.location = './registersuccess.php';</script>";

    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=http://www.websiteaddress.com/registersuccess.php">'; 
    $url = "http://www.websiteaddress.com/registersuccess.php";
    if(!headers_sent()) {
    //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
    } else {
        //If headers are sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript disabled, do html redirect.
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
    }

    mail("emailaddress@gmail.com","Registration $retuserkey",$email,"Subject");
}
```

Emails are sent both before and after the redirect. Both the emails are received but the redirect fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 301 redirect fails if headers are sent, the javascript redirect should work

Answer (score 0):

header() must be called before any actual output is sent and you have echo before it.

Comment: I have commented the echo first 2 echo statements before header() still the redirect doesnt happen

Comment: Check whether mailer->sendForReg or dbcontroller->dbregister have any output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do:

```
header('Location: '.$url);
exit;
```

after something has already been `echo`'d out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php.

If you move your `echo` statements so they only print when the redirect isn't happening, then you should be OK.

Comment: I have commented the echo first 2 echo statements before header() still the redirect doesnt happen

Comment: @user2563758 what do you see when the page is visited? Are there any messages in the error logs?

Comment: no messages in the error log. the user sits in the same page for ever without any message or redirect

Answer (score 0):

```
  header('Location: http://localhost/yourFileName.php');
    exit;
```

`header()` function is used /* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */ 
 `header()` function sends a raw HTTP header to a client

N.B: use right url

Comment: What does "N.B." mean?

Comment: @ Wayne Conrad,[N.B] is mean =nota bene

Comment: @Bleeding Fingers  header() function is used /* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */